# Alamofire POST method doesn't pass value to url

Tags: ios, swift, post, alamofire

I am using Alamofire for the networking in my application. In Alamofire, I am writing POST method to pass value to the url, but it is not passing any value. The is showing null. Below is my code:

```
let parameters = ["username": "\(textField.text)"]
let urlString = "**Some URL**"
Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in 
    guard response.result.error == nil else {
        print("error calling POST on email API")
        print(response.result.error!)
        return
    }

    if let value = response.result.value {
        print("The email is: \(value)" )
    }
}
```

If anyone get the mistake what I am doing wrong. Thank you!!

Comment: You are using swift 2.x?

Comment: yes! I am using swift 2.3.

Comment: What is the response coming? Are you getting json object from server or string? Verify!

Comment: The email is: {
    results = "<null>";
}  I was getting this as response.

Comment: simply pass `let parameters = ["username": textField.text!]` instead of `let parameters = ["username": "\(textField.text)"]` . However it may not make sense.

Comment: Same results. Its showing null.

Comment: okay, then check this on postman first. It may be encoding issue. You are encoding as a .JSON here. It might be default or none encoding

Comment: Its working fine on Postman. I already checked.

Comment: How are you passing parameters on postman. Is it in raw or in form data key value. (the username parameter)

Comment: Its in key value data not raw data.

Comment: then you should not be using `.JSON` as encoding. Keep it as none or default

Comment: Thanks! Its worked

Comment: What did you kept in encoding that made it worked

Comment: I kept it as a none.

Answer (score 5):

Which version of alamofire are you using?
Please try with URLEncoding.default instead of JSONEncoding.default.

Comment: Upvoted. Been scratching my head over this one for a bunch of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

let url =  NSURL(string:URLName)

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let data = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters!, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                if let json = json {
                    print(json)
                }

```
      request.HTTPBody = json!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);


            Alamofire.request(request)
                .responseString { response in
                    // do whatever you want here
                    print(response.result)
                    switch (response.result) {
                    case .Success(let JSON):
                       print(JSON)
                    case .Failure: break

                    }
            }
```

Comment: It is not the problem with `responseString`. It was the problem with encoding.

Comment: It's nothing like that.alamofire has encoding parameters of almost every type from Json to query string to form data

Answer (score 0):

Iam working with swift2.3 and i use Alamofire.. It's working for me:

```
class APIUtils: NSObject{static func fetchData(requestModel:RequestModel,completionBlock:(response:ResponseModel)->Void){

    let url = "\(requestModel.baseUrl)\(requestModel.apiUrl)"

    Alamofire.request(APIUtils().getHTTPMethod(requestModel.httpMethodType), url, parameters: requestModel.parametersDict,headers:requestModel.headersDict,encoding:(APIUtils().getEncodingFormat(requestModel.encodeType))).responseJSON { (responseObj) -> Void in

        let responseModel = ResponseModel()
        responseModel.responseCode = responseObj.response?.statusCode

        switch responseObj.result {
            case .Success(let data):
                if (data .isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)){
                    responseModel.responseDictionary = data as! NSDictionary
                }else if (data .isKindOfClass(NSArray)){
                    responseModel.customModel = data as! NSArray
                }
                responseModel.isSuccess = true
                break

            case .Failure(let error):

                responseModel.isSuccess = false

                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                break
        }

        completionBlock(response: responseModel)
    }
}

func getHTTPMethod(methodType:HTTPMethodType)->Alamofire.Method{
    switch(methodType){
        case .GET: return Alamofire.Method.GET
        case .POST: return Alamofire.Method.POST
        case .PUT: return Alamofire.Method.PUT
        case .PATCH: return Alamofire.Method.PATCH
        case .DELETE: return Alamofire.Method.DELETE

    }
}
func getEncodingFormat(methodType:encodingType)->Alamofire.ParameterEncoding{
    switch(methodType){
    case .URL: return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL
    case .JSON: return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON
    case .URLEncodedInURL: return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URLEncodedInURL

    }
}
```

}

//try this:

```
let urlencode = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding
    print(MyStrings.BaseURl+urlString)
    Alamofire.request(action, MyStrings.BaseURl+urlString, headers: headers, parameters:urlParams, encoding: isBody == true ? urlencode.JSON : urlencode.URLEncodedInURL)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { responseO in
            if (responseO.result.error == nil) {
                let responseModel = ResponseModel()
                responseModel.responseCode = responseO.response?.statusCode

                switch responseO.result {
                case .Success(let data):
                    if (data .isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)){
                        responseModel.responseDictionary = data as! NSDictionary
                    }else if (data .isKindOfClass(NSArray)){
                        responseModel.customModel = data as! NSArray
                    }
                    responseModel.isSuccess = true
                    break
                case .Failure(let error):
                    responseModel.isSuccess = false
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                    break
                }
                completionBlock(response: responseModel)
            }
            else {
                debugPrint("HTTP Request failed: \(responseO.result.error?.userInfo)")
                let responseModel = ResponseModel()
                responseModel.responseCode = responseO.response?.statusCode
                responseModel.isSuccess = false
                completionBlock(response: responseModel)
            }
    }
```